# Pandas crash when multiplying dataframe column with another

Tags: python, pandas, mod-wsgi

On my server running a python script (apache2, flask, debian config), I'm having a crash without any error output only when trying to multiply or divide dataframes columns (ex: df[col] = df[col] * or / df[another_column] ).

On my local computer, everything works perfectly but once running on the server, the execution just stops without any kind of indication at lines with a divide or multiply.

This error occurred after I tried to upgrade pandas on the sever. Here is a pip freeze of the config.

```
Cython==0.23.4
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Excel==0.0.4
Flask-Login==0.3.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
Flask-WTF==0.12
Flask-WhooshAlchemy==0.56
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
Pillow==3.3.0
Pygments==2.1.3
SQLAlchemy==1.0.14
Tempita==0.5.2
WTForms==2.1
Werkzeug==0.11.10
Whoosh==2.7.4
XlsxWriter==0.8.4
backports-abc==0.4
blinker==1.4
cycler==0.10.0
dask==0.10.1
decorator==4.0.10
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
ipython==5.0.0
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
itsdangerous==0.24
jdcal==1.2
jsonschema==2.5.1
matplotlib==1.5.1
mpmath==0.19
networkx==1.11
numexpr==2.6.1
numpy==1.10.4
openpyxl==2.3.5
pandas==0.17.1
path.py==8.2.1
patsy==0.4.1
pbr==1.8.1
pexpect==4.2.0
pickleshare==0.6
prompt-toolkit==1.0.3
psutil==4.3.0
ptyprocess==0.5.1
pyexcel==0.2.4
pyexcel-io==0.2.1
pyexcel-webio==0.0.7
pylab==0.1.3
pyparsing==2.1.5
python-dateutil==2.4.2
pytz==2015.7
pyzmq==15.2.0
requests==2.9.1
scikit-image==0.12.3
scikit-learn==0.17.1
scipy==0.17.1
seaborn==0.7.1
simplegeneric==0.8.1
six==1.10.0
sqlalchemy-migrate==0.10.0
sqlparse==0.2.0
statsmodels==0.6.1
sympy==1.0
texttable==0.8.4
toolz==0.8.0
tornado==4.4
traitlets==4.2.2
wcwidth==0.1.7
xlrd==0.9.4
xmltodict==0.10.2
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Are the Pandas versions (both server and local machine) the same?

Comment: Hello Abdou, yes both are Python 3.4

Comment: I am not talking about the Python versions. I am talking about the `Pandas` versions.

Comment: Sorry read too fast. Yes same pandas version (0.17.1)

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by ***crash without any error output***. Also, could you please show the data along with the code you are trying to run?

Comment: It is a silent error; it just stops whenever I do df[col] = df[col] * df[col_2]. Nothing else. When I try to change the name of the column then I receive a KeyError

Comment: Please show your data along with the `traceback` you get you try to change the name of the column.